# Translating equation into CSS calc causes "invalid property value"

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic, frontend

I'm attempting to translate the equation .00009441x^2 - .083x + 400, where x is 100vw, into a CSS calc() property. This is what I have so far:

```
div {
    height:calc(((100vw * .00009441) * (100vw * .00009441)) - (.083*100vw) + 400);
}
```

But Chrome keeps throwing an invalid property value error. How should I go about fixing this?

Approximate expected heights would be (Width x Height in px):

```
1184 by 435
1081 by 420
891 by 400
747 by 391
1326 by 455
```

Comment: not sure if ^ is allowed in calc , reference : https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation

Comment: +400 what ? vw, px, cm, ...

Comment: @GCyrillus px, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You can only go one set of brackets deep - you can't have nested calculations because those other mathematical symbols in CSS represent other selector criteria (+ is the adjacent sibling combinator, ^ is the attribute selector etc etc)

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, but the problem persists with: height:calc(((100vw * .00009441) * (100vw * .00009441)) - (.083*100vw) + 400);

Comment: Actually, you can only go one set of brackets deep - you can't have nested calculations because the +, *, - symbols in CSS represent other selector criteria (* is everything), (+ is the adjacent sibling combinator) etc etc I've amended my answer to integrate both reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I just played around with positioning and order of parenthesis and such until it worked. I think this achieved what you were trying to do? I hope...

```css
div {
      height: calc( ((100vw * .00009441)^2 - (.083*100vw) + 400));
      background: #000;
      width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Comment: the text being here is fooling you :(  .... but still not sure of what height value is expected here

Comment: I'm not sure either what the desired height is supposed to be, but my code snippet did not error in chrome dev tools, it used height property properly. Hopefully pokemonblack gets it working how they need.

Comment: Added the expcted values. Thanks for the help Matthew, but I'm not sure this is it. @GCyrillus

Comment: I think Paul's answer below is the correct one?  The ^ symbol is an attribute selector in CSS so it won't work in the context you are trying to use it in.

Comment: @EmilyChewy If it was just the ^, then manually squaring the value would resolve the issue, but calc(((100vw * .00009441) * (100vw * .00009441)) - (.083*100vw) + 400) doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You can't go more than one set of brackets deep - i've tweaked the wording of my answer.  It's not just the ^ symbol, but also + and - that have other uses in CSS.

Comment: @pokemonblack1000 : Depending on what your viewport width is, you may end up with a negative value? I did it on the calculator and substituted 100vw for 533, and your equation equaled  -42.38....

Comment: @pokemonblack1000 - can you mark Paul's amended answer as correct.  It is the correct answer.